# singleton using enum

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I read a lot on stackoverflow regarding the creation of singleton classes using enum.
I must have missed something because i can't reach the INSTANCE anywhere.

this is my code:

```
public class UserActivity {

    private DataSource _dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate _jdbcTemplate;

    static enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;

        private static final UserActivity singleton = new UserActivity();

        public UserActivity getSingleton() {
            return singleton;
        }
    }

    public UserActivity() {
        this._dataSource = MysqlDb.getInstance().getDataSource();
        this._jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this._dataSource);
    }

    public void dostuff() {
     ...
    }
}
```

and outside I'm trying to do

```
UserActivity.INSTANCE.getSingleton()
```

or

```
UserActivity.Singleton.
```

but eclipse's code completion doesn't find anything

thanks!

Comment: See here http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=3

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The trick is to make the enum itself the singleton.  Try this:

```
public enum UserActivity {
    INSTANCE;

    private DataSource _dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate _jdbcTemplate;

    private UserActivity() {
        this._dataSource = MysqlDb.getInstance().getDataSource();
        this._jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this._dataSource);
    }

    public void dostuff() {
     ...
    }
}

// use it as ...
UserActivity.INSTANCE.doStuff();
```

Answer (score 13):

`INSTANCE` is a member of `Singleton`, not of `UserActivity` - so you'd need:

```
UserActivity.Singleton.INSTANCE.getSingleton();
```

However, you haven't actually made `UserActivity` a singleton - normally you'd make the type itself an enum, not embed an enum *within* the type...

Comment: Hiya.. for some reason I'm still kind of lost. I never used enum for a singleton class before. mind showing a small example ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UserActivity {

    private DataSource _dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate _jdbcTemplate;

    private static enum Singleton { // private, why not
        INSTANCE;

        private static final UserActivity singleton = new UserActivity();

        public UserActivity getSingleton() {
            return singleton;
        }
    }

    private UserActivity() { // private !!(*)
        this._dataSource = MysqlDb.getInstance().getDataSource();
        this._jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this._dataSource);
    }


    public static UserActivity getInstance() {
     return UserActivity.Singleton.INSTANCE.getSingleton();
    } 

    public void dostuff() {
     ...
    }
}
```

and call `UserActivity.getInstance().doStuff();`

You can't call the constructor (*) and you can only get an instance of your UserActivity() class via the INSTANCE in the private enum - which is guaranteed to be created once and only once

Comment: @NimC : Oh come on - it is. ufk was using the Lazy Load singleton pattern of which you are a well known enemy (:P) and was trying to make it work - the accepted answer was just taking the enum on the top level simplifying things

Comment: the enum will only be loaded on demand anyway (by the classloader), this has no advantage.

Comment: @NimChimpsky : yes but the question was about how to make _this_ dialect work - not the top level enum one. One might want to know how one can make one's code work - out of curiosity - even if there are simpler ways to do things. The discussion for the differences between those idioms belongs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883051/enum-and-singletons-top-level-vs-nested-enum) and is not settled IMHO :)